# Calling function from (Qt) plugin fails

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

I want to write an application which consists of several plugins. My idea is that the plugin itself is always just a factory which then can create the required object.

So I created an Interface for the pluginfactory called AbstractFactoryPlugin with a pure virtual method called create. Because of the fact that I want to have several different plugins (factories) with the same interface I can’t put the Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE macro in the AbstractFactoryPlugin header file.

So for a sample plugin I created an Interface which inherits from AbstractFactoryPlugin called IMyObjectFactoryPlugin and declared this interface with the DECLARE macro. Further the MyObjectFactoryPlugin then inherits from QObject and IMyObjectFactoryPlugin.

But when I load the plugin and call the create function, the create function of MyObjectFactoryPlugin seems to be never called. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanx in advance.

Sourcecode:

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTPLUGINFACTORY_H
#define ABSTRACTPLUGINFACTORY_H

#include "IAnObject.h"

class AbstractFactoryPlugin
{
    public:
        virtual ~AbstractFactoryPlugin() {}

        virtual IAnObject *create(QObject *parent) = 0;
};

#endif // ABSTRACTPLUGINFACTORY_H
```

---

```
#ifndef IMYOBJECTFACTORYPLUGIN_H
#define IMYOBJECTFACTORYPLUGIN_H

#include "AbstractFactoryPlugin.h"

#include <QtPlugin>

class IMyObjectFactoryPlugin : public AbstractFactoryPlugin
{
    public:
        virtual ~IMyObjectFactoryPlugin() {}
};


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(IMyObjectFactoryPlugin,
                    "org.MyObjectFactoryPlugin");
QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // IMYOBJECTFACTORYPLUGIN_H
```

---

```
#ifndef MYOBJECTPLUGIN_H
#define MYOBJECTPLUGIN_H

#include <QtPlugin>
#include "IMyObjectFactoryPlugin.h"
#include "AbstractFactoryPlugin.h"

class MyObjectFactoryPlugin : public QObject, IMyObjectFactoryPlugin
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.MyObjectFactoryPlugin" )
    Q_INTERFACES(IMyObjectFactoryPlugin)

    public:
        MyObjectFactoryPlugin(QObject *parent = 0);
        IAnObject *create(QObject *parent);
};

#endif // MYOBJECTPLUGIN_H
```

---

```
#include "MyObject.h"
#include "MyObjectFactoryPlugin.h"
#include <QDebug>

MyObjectFactoryPlugin::MyObjectFactoryPlugin(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

}

IAnObject *MyObjectFactoryPlugin::create(QObject *parent)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "was called";
    return new MyObject();
}
```

---

```
#ifndef IANOBJECT_H
#define IANOBJECT_H

class IAnObject
{
    public:
        IAnObject() {isInitialized = false;}
        virtual ~IAnObject() {}

        virtual bool initialize() = 0;

    protected:
        bool isInitialized;
};

#endif // IANOBJECT_H
```

---

```
#include "IAnObject.h"

#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

class MyObject : public IAnObject
{
    public:
        MyObject();
        bool initialize();
};

#endif // MYOBJECT_H
```

---

```
#include "MyObject.h"

MyObject::MyObject()
{
}


bool MyObject::initialize()
{
    return true;
}
```

---

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QPluginLoader>
#include <QDebug>

#include <E:/QtProjects/_test_PlugIn/MyPlugin/AbstractFactoryPlugin.h>
#include <E:/QtProjects/_test_PlugIn/MyPlugin/IAnObject.h>
#include <E:/QtProjects/_test_PlugIn/MyPlugin/IMyObjectFactoryPlugin.h>

IAnObject *loadPlugin()
{
    QDir dir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());

    qDebug() << dir;

    foreach(QString fileName, dir.entryList(QDir::Files))
    {
        QPluginLoader pluginLoader(dir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
        QObject *plugin = pluginLoader.instance();

        qDebug() << fileName;

        if(plugin)
        {
            qDebug() << "##### Plugin load ok #####";

            AbstractFactoryPlugin *abstractFactoryPlugin = reinterpret_cast<AbstractFactoryPlugin *>(plugin);

            return abstractFactoryPlugin->create(NULL);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "loadPlugin:" << loadPlugin();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Did you try dynamic_cast instead of reinterpret_cast?

Comment: With a dynamic_cast the application crashes. Stepping through with the debugger results in an exception:---------------------------
Exception Triggered
---------------------------
<p>The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception.<p>Stopped in thread 0 by: 
Exception at 0xad1aad, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance).
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Answer (score 1):

Any Qt5 plugin must inherit from QObject, if you want your base class to be independent from QObject you'll have to create an intermediary class that inherits both AbstractFactoryPlugin and QObject (let's call it AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin).

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTMYOBJECTFACTORYPLUGIN_H
#define ABSTRACTMYOBJECTFACTORYPLUGIN_H

#include "AbstractFactoryPlugin.h"

class AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin : public QObject, public AbstractFactoryPlugin
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { }
  virtual ~AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin() { }
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin,
                    "org.AbstractFactoryPlugin");

#endif // ABSTRACTMYOBJECTFACTORYPLUGIN_H
```

---

To create a plugin, you'll have to inherit from this class and override the create() method:

```
class MyObjectFactoryPlugin : public AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_INTERFACES(AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin)
  Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.MyObjectFactoryPlugin" FILE "MyObjectFactoryPlugin.json")
public:
  MyObjectFactoryPlugin(QObject* parent = 0) : AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin(parent) { }
  virtual IAnObject *create(QObject *parent);
  virtual ~MyObjectFactoryPlugin() { }
};
```

---

To cast the loaded plugin (a QObject) to AbstractFactoryPlugin safetly, you'll have to cast it to the intermediary class first.

```
AbstractFactoryPlugin * objectFactoryPlugin = qobject_cast< AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin * >(plugin);
```

The implicit assignment will cast it to the right base class.

*Note: You'll have to check if the cast is successful first if you have other inheritance trees.*

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Qt5. That is why I don't use Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2 because it have been deprecated but using the Q_PLUGIN_METADATA macro instead. Editing my code as you suggested works. But isn't it a problem putting the Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE in AbstractFactoryPlugin if I want to derive more plugins from AbstractFactoryPlugin because of the same identifier of the Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE macro? That is why I tried to avoid this as I have written in my first post: “Because of the fact that I want to have several different plugins (factories) with the same interface I can’t put the Q_DE…”

Comment: I updated my answer, this works for me; although I'm not clear if this is what you're after.

Comment: It works except for one thing. I derive another Plugin from AbstractFactoryPlugin (eg AbstractOtherObjectFactoryPlugin). If this plugin is loaded this cast works although it should return 0:qobject_cast<AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin* >(plugin). Changing the Identifier of Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE from  org.AbstractFactoryPlugin to org. AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin for AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin and to org. AbstractOtherObjectFactoryPlugin for AbstractOtherObjectFactoryPlugin seems to work better. Isn’t it better to let every Interface have it’s own identifier? Or am I doing it wrong this way?

Comment: All of your plugins should inherit directly from `AbstractMyObjectFactoryPlugin`, which is actually just a `QObject` wrapped around `AbstractFactoryPlugin`, if you want to inherit from `AbstractFactoryPlugin` directly you can, but only inside the same application (plugins inheriting from `AbstractFactoryPlugin` shouldn't work at all, but do so in your tests because they have an identical signature)